# How strong is each level of Atari 2600's Video Chess?

Tags: rating, computer-chess

I used to play Video Chess on Atari with my dad when I was a kid.  What is the approximate FIDE rating of each level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Atari 2600 has bugs which make the higher levels unrateable. It is reputed to be slightly better than Microchess, according to a [chess.com article](https://www.chess.com/blog/BenRedic/retro-computer-chess-part-4-atari-video-chess-1979).

Atari had a very limited book which makes it weaker than current approaches.

An ESTIMATE of the strength is as follows:

Level Time Rating(?):

8        10       700

1        15       800

2        30      1000

3        45      1100

4       165      1300

5       195      1350

6       720        ??

7     36000        ??

Comment: Chess dotcom article made the claim noted.  Estimates are mine.